# Swift - Multiple textfields updating instead of one

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am trying to save the inputs of multiple `TextField`s in an array, but when I try to enter a text in either of the text fields in the first iteration of the VStack, the text in the next iteration also updates, and vice versa.

Here is what I tried:

```
@State var numberOfFlashcards: Int = 2
@State var question: String = ""
@State var answer: String = ""
```

```
ForEach(1...numberOfFlashcards, id:\.self){ index in
    Text("Flashcard \(index)")
    VStack{
        // question text field
        TextField(text: $question) {
            Text("Enter question")
        }
                                
        // answer text field
        TextField(text: $answer) {
            Text("Enter answer")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need each pair of quaestion and answer to be bound to a separate instance of the variable. So a simple way to do this -

1. Create a structure, like:

```
struct QA: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var question: String = ""
    var answer: String = ""
}
```

2. Then in your view create an array of that structure as your state:

```
@State var qas = [QA](repeating: QA(), count: 2)
```

3. And bind each instance in array to each instance of the text field in `ForEach` in your view (as `$qas[index].<...>`):

```
VStack {
   ForEach(qas.indices, id: \.self){ index in
       Text("Flashcard \(qas[index].question)")
       // question text field
       TextField(text: $qas[index].question) {
           Text("Enter question")
       }
       
       // answer text field
       TextField(text: $qas[index].answer) {
           Text("Enter answer")
       }
   }
}
```

(I moved VStack to the top of the hierarchy, as otherwise all items ar overlapping, unless you already have it somewhere higher up, so it may not be actually required)

Comment: Follow-up question:

Say I want to add the qas array and another variable to a dictionary, how do I go about it?

I'm thinking the dictionary should be outside the view so I can save the inputs from this view every time I run it

Comment: @omoge Generally I would move all the data, including `qas` to a `ViewModel` of this view you are creating (i.e. to move to MVVM pattern). If you need to store this data even longer than view exists, then you probably will need a separate class for that (not a ViewModel). And then to communicate with that class, you can either directly bind a view to a variable in the class that outlives the view. Or you can still store the `@State` in the ViewModel (or view), and pass `qas` to a that class on some event (e.g. `.onDisappear`) - depends what that class is needed for.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$question` and `$answer` are binding and refer to the same variables that are defined in the outer scope, each value of `$question` or `$answer` in a flashcard is going to be the same for all of the flashcards.

Comment: How do you suggest I go about making them refer to different variables?

Comment: One way could be to have a container of questions and answers. This could be implemented a few ways, like an object with a ``question`` and ``answer`` variable, and then doing an array of said object (the count would be the same as ``numberOfFlashcards``). You could also create parallel arrays– one for questions and one for answers.